# Protocol not available on SO_ACCEPTCONN

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I tried the following code and got the error `OSError: [Errno 92] Protocol not available`. What am I doing wrong ?

```
import socket

s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_ACCEPTCONN, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve in the first place by using this option. But in [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) it clearly says:

> SO_ACCEPTCONN
>   Returns a value indicating whether or not this socket has been marked to accept connections with listen(2). The value 0 indicates that this is not a listening socket, the value 1 indicates that this is a listening socket. **This socket option is read-only.**

Thus, it makes no sense to use this option with `setsockopt` (writing) and that's why it is unsupported. Only using it with `getsockopt` (reading) would make sense.